# How to modify objects in django ListView?

Tags: django

I have a ListView for a blog with fields of "title" and "text".
How to change "text" for example I want to summarize it something like *text[:100]*

I don't want to change the database. I think the solution is modifying get_queryset but don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify objects on the ListView. You can easily use @property method on the model to get such results.

```
@property
def text_summary(self):
    return self.title[:100]
```

Then you can access this method like a normal field of a model anywhere e.g. on template {{ blog.text_summary }}